# Bricked my SD card while using `dd`

Tags: sd-card, dd

To extract `Raspbian-NOOBS` onto my 32GB SD card, I mistakenly used the form of `dd` command meant for an `iso` image

```
dd if=/home/ubuntu.iso of=/dev/sdc bs=2M
```

for a `zip` file (I know, I am dumb!)

```
dd if=/home/NOOBS_v2_4_0.zip of=/dev/sdc bs=2M
```

and consequently bricked my SD card.

The system on which I used `dd` is Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Of course the card didn't work when inserted in Raspberry Pi 3B, but on Ubuntu 16.04 this is what it looks like (see `sdc`) on doing `lsblk`:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   100M  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0 249.9G  0 part 
└─sda3   8:3    0 215.8G  0 part 
sdb      8:16   0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   0 919.6G  0 part /
├─sdb2   8:18   0     1K  0 part 
└─sdb5   8:21   0  11.9G  0 part [SWAP]
sdc      8:32   1  29.8G  0 disk 
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

whereas, what a healthy (16GB) card should look like (again, `sdc`) is:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   100M  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0 249.9G  0 part 
└─sda3   8:3    0 215.8G  0 part 
sdb      8:16   0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   0 919.6G  0 part /
├─sdb2   8:18   0     1K  0 part 
└─sdb5   8:21   0  11.9G  0 part [SWAP]
sdc      8:32   1  14.9G  0 disk 
└─sdc1   8:33   1  14.9G  0 part /media/user/6339-3036
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

Another detail: I wrote to `/dev/sdc` instead of `/dev/sdc1`. How do I repair the bricked SD card?

Most questions are about how to recover lost data and are not useful for me; I just want the bricked card to be functional again -- even if completely formatted!

Comment: Also, if all you did was dd a zip file, just format the disk or dd a proper image to it.

Comment: try partitioning it

Comment: Any specific recommendation for a partitioning software on Ubuntu, @ravery ?

Comment: gparted is my favorite

Comment: @ravery : gparted shows the whole disk as unallocated and does not show the option to format the drive.

@muru : will try over-writing with `dd` and let you know.

Comment: on mac, use https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8132218

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The disk is not bricked - a bricked device is completely non-functional, but the disk shows up in `lsblk` and has the size listed, so it is functional. You can create a new partition table on it using `fdisk` or `parted` if you don't mind command line tools:

```
sudo parted /dev/sdc mklabel msdos
sudo parted /dev/sdc mkpart primary ext4 0 100%
```

Also, when `dd`ing an image, you usually `dd` to the disk and not to a partition on it, so `dd of=/dev/sdc` is usually fine when the input is an ISO or an OS image.

Comment: On trying the first command, I got:  

    `Information: You may need to update /etc/fstab.`

which I can worry about later, but running the second command gives a warning:  

    `Warning: The resulting partition is not properly aligned for best performance.
    Ignore/Cancel?`

Is this normal?

Comment: It's normal. parted thinks we're talking of spinning rust because that's how the disk presents itself, but it isn't.

Comment: After trying what you suggested, I have an unnamed partition `└─sdc1   8:33   1  29.7G  0 part`. To add this device to `/etc/fstab`, I would need the `blkid`, but the device does not show up when I do `blkid`.

What am I missing? Note: I am not an expert. I am just following the steps. :)

Comment: @user128785 why would you add it to fstab? O.o

Comment: Because the output of first command? But may be not. As I said, beginner here. Sorry.

But when I remove the sd card and insert again, though it shows in `lsblk`, it does not show up as a regular formatted SD card would in Nautilus. How do I get that? Can you send some reference which I can follow? Or if it is a matter of 1 or 2 steps, tell me how to proceed.

Comment: I just reformatted the card to FAT32 using gparted, and it shows in Nautilus. Essentially, what you suggested worked. I have one more card to be rescued in a similar situation, so thanks. Accepting your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the operating systems for Raspberry Pi are distributed as [compressed] image files. They can be installed in a similar way as what you tried.

But NOOBs is installed in a different way, as you already found out.

- You can probably use **gparted** to create an MSDOS partrition table and a FAT32 partition. If it does not work, you can use **[mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb)** to restore the card to a standard storage device.
- Then you can extract the files from the zip file to the FAT32 partition.

  All the steps are explained with details in the following link,

  [www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/noobs.md](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/noobs.md)

  > To set up a blank SD card with NOOBS:
  >
  > - Format an SD card which is 8GB or larger as FAT. See the instructions given below.
  > - Download and extract the files from the NOOBS zip file.
  > - Copy the extracted files onto the SD card that you just formatted, so that this file is at the root directory of the SD card. Please note
  >     that in some cases it may extract the files into a folder; if this is
  >     the case, then please copy across the files from inside the folder
  >     rather than the folder itself.
  > - On first boot, the "RECOVERY" FAT partition will be automatically resized to a minimum, and a list of OSes that are available to install
  >     will be displayed.

Comment: This is how I used to do it earlier, but then I decided to use `dd` and this happened.

Comment: Try the good old way again. Good luck :-)

Comment: This should be the top answer